# asp.net framework

Tags: asp.net, framework

a la hora de crear un proyecto en visual studio, me salta este error, estoy tratando de crear una aplicacion web con asp.net framework y no lo he podido solucionar.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: de casualidad estás con un proyecto de win forms?

Comment: quiero trabajar en una aplicación web

Comment: Creo que se le puede ayudar mejor si en lugar de solo colocra el pantallazo de error describe cada uno de los pasos que está realizando para recrear el error que se le produce: 1) Abrir Visual Studio (si esta abriendolo desde un acceso directo indicar los parametros de linea de comandos con que se está abriendo o incluso tomar una lectura desde el administrador de tareas de windows de la linea de comandos con que está abriendo la instancia) 2) Ir al menu X... . Tambien es util que revise la ventana de salida, a ver si ahí le da mas detalles del error. Tambien puede ser instalacion incompleta

Answer (score 0):

visual studio crea por defecto, en Documentos, que se llama (IISExpress), cambia el nombre de esta carpeta, cualquier nombre, no importa, luego cierra visual studio, y vuelve a crear o abrir un proyecto y se creara otra carpeta (IISExpress) y con esto se habrá solucionado el error.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).